# The totalBytesExpectedToWrite of setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock block returns -1

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Where the `totalBytesExpectedToWrite` information comes from? At the moment it returns `-1` for me, but it was returning proper size earlier. Is it from server information that now is not sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue arose due to some sudden changes on my server, the files were delivered without file size in the header thus `AFNetworking` was giving `-1`. Once correct behaviour re-instantiated on server everything returned to normal state.